# Is there a way to echo every line of JavaScript as it is executed?

Tags: javascript

I have two programs that should be running the same . They are not. I'd like to see where their execution diverges. Is there an option in Chrome or Firefox or Safari to log/echo every line of JavaScript as it is executed ? Or some other way to do this short of manually adding console.log every few lines? Note: the divergence is 10k or 20k maybe 100k lines deep and ideally I'd want it to print variables similar to the Chrome dev tools.

Then I can just dump the logs and find the divergence

Stepping through the code in the debugger is not a solution as it would take hours if not days to step that far.

One idea is to use a babel or uglify plugin to use the last to emit code for each line to print what it is about to do or just did.

Another idea is if there is a way to dump all of memory from js so I can compare all objects and all references. They should be the same so when I see two dumps that differ I'll have found my bug. note: JSON.stringify is not an option as I need to see all variables/objects/classes etc.

Note: I'm not looking for basic answers like "use console.log" or "step in the debugger". I appreciate the help and maybe I've overlooked something simple but I do have quite a bit of JavaScript experience.

Maybe an example would help. Imagine you got the source to an app as large as google docs. You run some processor over it that's not supposed to break anything or change anything. Except it does. You look at the changes and can't see anything wrong. All you know is when you run it it runs but a few things are subtly broken. So you put a breakpoint there and see the data is bad. But when did it go bad? You don't know the code (you just got it). It could have been 100s of thousands of lines before. You have no idea where to put breakpoints or console.logs. It could take weeks. But, given you know the code should run exactly the same if you could print all lines of execution you'd find the bug in minutes instead of days.

Comment: No, but you can set a break point and walk through the code or manually add console.log lines.

Comment: You could read [Chrome DevTools Step-Code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code)

Comment: Using a debugger and binary search to find the point of deviation should be doable.

Comment: Use `console.log()` to log things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions but none of these comments are answers to the question whatsoever. I didn't ask how to debug or how to use chrome devtools. I asked *Is there a way to echo every line of JavaScript as it is executed?*

Comment: @gman Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `debugger;` at the begin of the `function()` or where you want and **open the console**.

When the `debugger` is reached it stop the execution. After that you can execute code step by step and add some watches.

It works fine with all recent browser.

Example :

```js
function test()
{
 var rand = Math.random();
 debugger;
 return rand;
}

test();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this is not answer to the question. The question is not how to debug, the question is *Is there a way to echo every line of JavaScript as it is executed?*

Answer (score 0):

It is node js but it may be helpful for you. set the NODE_V8_COVERAGE environment variable to a directory, coverage data will be output to that directory when the program exits.
https://blog.npmjs.org/post/178487845610/rethinking-javascript-test-coverage