Without a debugger, I want to add a cosole.log(linenumber); to every line of my javascript. How?
Debuggers are a bad way to trace through code in my experience. I want to write to the console the entire trace of the program to see what's executed when.
I suspect using an abstract syntax tree is a good way to go about this, but the code I have doing it doesn't work.
Even for things like:
if (true) alert('hi');
I want it to turn into:
if (true) {console.log(16); alert('hi');}
This is doable, but I'm not a javascript wizard to do this. Please help me!
Things I tried:
I want more than every function, every single line:
Adding console.log to every function automatically
I also tried this, which seems like it's on the right track, but isn't working as expected. It misses most lines:
const esprima = require('esprima');
const escodegen = require('escodegen');
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the JavaScript code from a file
const code = fs.readFileSync('input.js', 'utf-8');

// Parse the JavaScript code into an AST
const ast = esprima.parseScript(code, { loc: true });

// Function to add console.log statement at the end of a line
function addConsoleLog(node) {
  const consoleLogNode = {
    type: 'ExpressionStatement',
    expression: {
      type: 'CallExpression',
      callee: {
        type: 'MemberExpression',
        object: { type: 'Identifier', name: 'console' },
        property: { type: 'Identifier', name: 'log' },
      },
      arguments: [{ type: 'Literal', value: node.loc.end.line }],
    },
  };

  return consoleLogNode;
}

// Traverse the AST and add console.log statements
function traverseAST(node) {
  if (node.type === 'Program' || node.type === 'BlockStatement') {
    for (let i = 0; i < node.body.length; i++) {
      traverseAST(node.body[i]);
      if (node.body[i].type !== 'FunctionDeclaration' && node.body[i].type !== 'VariableDeclaration') {
        node.body.splice(i + 1, 0, addConsoleLog(node.body[i]));
        i++;
      }
    }
  } else if (node.type === 'IfStatement') {
    traverseAST(node.consequent);
    if (node.alternate) {
      traverseAST(node.alternate);
    }
  } else if (node.type === 'ForStatement' || node.type === 'WhileStatement' || node.type === 'DoWhileStatement') {
    traverseAST(node.body);
  } else if (node.type === 'TryStatement') {
    traverseAST(node.block);
    if (node.handler) {
      traverseAST(node.handler.body);
    }
    if (node.finalizer) {
      traverseAST(node.finalizer);
    }
  } else if (node.type === 'SwitchStatement') {
    node.cases.forEach(traverseAST);
  } else if (node.type === 'ConditionalExpression') {
    if (node.consequent.type !== 'CallExpression' && node.consequent.type !== 'AssignmentExpression') {
      node.consequent = {
        type: 'SequenceExpression',
        expressions: [node.consequent, addConsoleLog(node)],
      };
    }
    if (node.alternate.type !== 'CallExpression' && node.alternate.type !== 'AssignmentExpression') {
      node.alternate = {
        type: 'SequenceExpression',
        expressions: [node.alternate, addConsoleLog(node)],
      };
    }
  }
}

// Traverse the AST and add console.log statements
traverseAST(ast);

// Generate the modified JavaScript code
const modifiedCode = escodegen.generate(ast);

// Write the modified code to a file
fs.writeFileSync('output.js', modifiedCode);


Also similar to this question without an answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41549961/is-there-a-way-to-echo-every-line-of-javascript-as-it-is-executed
